# React Native Flatlist rendering items

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am not able to show my flatlist and I am not sure whether my coding is correct. There is no output if when I run this. It will only show a white screen. My data is correct which is this.props.section.songs. I want to show the title and artist in my text but I am unable to do that.

```
export default class SongList extends Component
  {
     renderSongsList() { 

         return( 
             <View>
                 <FlatList
                     data = {this.props.section.songs}
                     renderItem={(song, sectionId, rowId) => (
                         <TouchableOpacity onPress={ () => Actions.Player({songIndex: parseInt( rowId ),songs: this.props.section.songs, section: this.props.section }) }>
                         <View key={song}  style={ styles.song }>
                             <Text style={styles.itemTitle}>
                               { song.title}
                             </Text >
                             <Text style={styles.itemArtist}>
                               { song.artist }
                             </Text>
                           </View>
                         </TouchableOpacity>
                     )}
                 />
             </View>
         );              
       } 
   render() 
   {
   return (
       <View>     
       { this.renderSongsList() }
       </View>
   );}}
```

Comment: Please double check what are you receiving in the song variable inside render row method ... flatList provide the data item in variable {item} you have to destruct it.

Answer (score 1):

```
    export default class SongList extends Component
      {
     renderSongsList() { 

         return( 
             <View>
                 <FlatList
                     data = {this.props.section.songs}
```

// You have to cross check the values you receive here. Better is to receive a array item
//here and pass to the render props
// Or try {song, sectionId, rowId} this in place of (song, sectionId, rowId) see below

```
                     renderItem={({song, sectionId, rowId}) => (
                         <TouchableOpacity onPress={ () => Actions.Player({songIndex: parseInt( rowId ),songs: this.props.section.songs, section: this.props.section }) }>
                         <View key={song}  style={ styles.song }>
                             <Text style={styles.itemTitle}>
                               { song.title}
                             </Text >
                             <Text style={styles.itemArtist}>
                               { song.artist }
                             </Text>
                           </View>
                         </TouchableOpacity>
                     )}
                 />
             </View>
         );              
       } 
   render() 
   {
   return (
       <View>     
       { this.renderSongsList() }
       </View>
   );}}
```

Comment: It still doesnt work. The data I should be getting is the title and artist which is songs:
    [
      {
        id: '1',
        title: 'Better Now',
        artist: 'Post Malone',
      },
      {
        id: '2',
        title: 'Despacito',
        artist: 'Luis Fonsi',
      },
    ]

Comment: Ok,  <FlatList
                     data = {this.props.section.songs}
                     renderItem={(item) => this.renderItem(item)}
                 />

Comment: Than here Item is one idex of the array data you are passing here. Now in render method  you can access the elements as follows

Comment: renderitem(item){ console.log(item.id)}    access data like this

Answer (score 0):

```
export default class SongList extends Component
  {
     renderItems(item){
    // Here you can access all items of your json by item.property  
    // Like your JSON is { id: '1', title: 'Better Now', artist: 'Post Malone', }
    // You can access these values as item.id, item.title etc       
    }

     renderSongsList() { 

         return( 
             <View>
                 <FlatList
                     data = {this.props.section.songs}
                     renderItem={(item) => this.renderItems(item)}
                 />
             </View>
         );              
       } 
   render() 
   {
   return (
       <View>     
       { this.renderSongsList() }
       </View>
   );}}
```